# Javascript URLs with MVC cause problems with Index pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Basic problem is this:

Got a page, with a control, that invokes an ajax call.

URL for the ajax call is `var url = 'someAjaxUrl';`

I'm on the page

> mysite.com/bibble/controller/ViewFish

When ajax is invoked with the url, it will go for this method:

> mysite.com/bibble/controller/someAjaxUrl

This is great. However, if I decide to make my ViewFish page the index of the controller, the url becomes:

`mysite.com/bibble/controller`

This breaks the ajax, because the ajax now goes to

> mysite.com/bibble/someAjaxUrl

Is there a simple solution for this that will ensure the javascript always works?

If you manually type in

> mysite.com/bibble/controller/Index

it works. But the URLs are generated via `ActionLink()` which automatically omits the `/Index` for you.

Thoughts welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thoughts welcome

Don't hardcode urls:

```
var url = 'someAjaxUrl';
```

Use the built-in url helpers instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("someAction", "someController")';
</script>
```

or if you are unobtrusively AJAXifying some DOM element such as an anchor or a form you could simply use its href or action property.

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "someAction", "someController", null, new { id = "myAnchor" })
```

and then in your separate javascript:

```
$('#myAnchor').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This way you don't even need an `url` variable. You already have it as part of the DOM.

This could also work for divs or other elements:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-url="@Url.Action("someAction", "someController")">
    Click me
</div>
```

and then:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Huh. For some reason it never occurred to me to use this for javascript variable urls. Thanks.

Comment: In an ASP.NET MVC application you should absolutely always use url helpers when dealing with urls and never hardcode them.